# what is the significance of the output of this command ? Cisco CLI

Tags: cisco, cli

When i enter this command i get my neighbors with some IPs and these are not their Telnet IPs.
Can you tell me where those IP belong to ?

> sh cdp entry * protocol

I want to know what are those IPs?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the prefix name "RTR_" those devices are routers.

Routers generally have several IP addresses, so CDP may display only one of those IP addresses. (Well, even layer 2 switches can have several IP addresses.)

From [this post by MAG03 on Experts-Exchange.com](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/27217634/How-is-the-ip-address-that-shows-in-CDP-determined.html#a36446165), which is consistent with what I see right now one some switches, it seems that:

> CDP determines the IP address to use by first looking at the directly
>   connected interface and seeing if there is an IP address on it. If
>   there is, that IP address will be used. If the link is a trunk CDP
>   will choose the lowest IP address of the vlan interfaces as the IP
>   address it will use to describe the neighbor.
>
> so if SW1 has vlans with IP 1.1.1.1 and another vlan with ip 2.2.2.2,
>   SW2 has vlans with IP addresses of 3.3.3.3 and 4.4.4.4, and the link
>   connecting the two is a trunk.
>
> Given that CDP is enabled on the trunk interface SW1 will be shown as
>   having an address of 1.1.1.1 and SW2 will have an addess of 3.3.3.3 in
>   the show cdp neighbor detail output.

Usually the IP used to manage a device is the loopback IP and so is never directly connected to a CDP neighbor and is unlikely to be shown in your CDP command

However if you issue the `show cdp neighbors detail`command you will see this IP address.

Notes:

- the behavior may change depending on the IOS version, and is also different between IOS and NX-OS, probably for CAT-OS too.
- you mentioned telnet, which is totally insecure, you should disable telnet and use SSH instead.